# How to access a particular DOM element using ELementRef or @ViewChild in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to include the nouislider in a component in angular2. I have copied most of the code from here--
"https://github.com/tb/ng2-nouislider/blob/master/src/nouislider.ts"

I was able to make it work as an independent component, but I my business login requires it to have in the other component.

After placing the code in a component, I'm getting following error:
ERROR Error: noUiSlider (10.0.0): create requires a single element, got: null

this is my HTML snippet:

```
<div #nouiSliderinput [attr.disabled]="disabled ? true : undefined"></div>
```

this is my component snippet where I'm facing the error:

```
inputsConfig.format = this.format || this.config.format || new 
DefaultFormatter();
this.slider = noUiSlider.create(
  this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.nouiSliderinput'),
  Object.assign(this.config, inputsConfig)
);

this.handles =
[].slice.call(this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.noUi-handle'));
```

I'm unable to use "nativeElement.querySelector('.nouiSliderinput')", this is returning null.

Is there a way to get the access the DOM element using the Id or class.

Comment: You copied the code from the github repo? Why are you not using npm? With your approach you can't receive any updates/bugfixes of the package. Also if you get more and more packages this way it will be a nightmare to keep them updated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I acknowledge that I would be difficult to update the this way, But my project requires it to be AOT compilable. Therefore, I'm not using any plugins or jquery to support AOT compilation.

Comment: Looks like aot should not be an issue : https://github.com/tb/ng2-nouislider/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aclosed%20aot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to access `nouiSliderinput`. You can access it by using `nativeElement`. It returns the same object as `querySelector`

```
@ViewChild('nouiSliderinput') public nouiSliderinput: ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {
    // you will get the element by below line
    console.log(this.nouiSliderinput.nativeElement);
}
```

Comment: It is throwing the following error: 
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined**

also, same error when I put it in ngAfterViewInit() angular hook.

Comment: can u pls confirm that `<div #nouiSliderinput [attr.disabled]="disabled ? true : undefined"></div>` is not inside any `*ngIf` condition and u can see the content inside the div on screen ?

Comment: My Bad! Yes, the HTML snippet is in `*ngIf` condition. Thanks for the observation.

Comment: instead of `*ngIf` u should go with `[hidden]` it does the same job and u will be able to access `this.nouiSliderinput.nativeElement`